# ChaosMonkey for k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, resilience-testing

Is there a kind of tool like ChaosMonkey specific for k8s that kill nodes and pods during office hours to train the team how to deal with issues and to harden the k8s cluster?

It is possible to create a script or program that kills random PODs, but if such a tool already exists then this will save time.

Comment: Chaos Monkey works on k8s, it works on all systems handled by spinnaker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at [kube-monkey](https://github.com/asobti/kube-monkey). According to the `README`, it randomly causes failures in kubernetes clusters.

Answer (score 4):

check this out, it's a very good guide [Run Chaos Experiments Without Risking Your Job](https://blog.loadmill.com/run-chaos-experiments-without-risking-your-job-2c8a5f4b0bfc)

Another one [Powerfulseal](https://github.com/bloomberg/powerfulseal) powerful testing tool for kubernetes which adds chaos into a cluster.